# Rapidly requesting a file from a server

Tags: python

Here is a Python script I wrote earlier for rapidly requesting a file from a server and timing each transaction. Can I improve this script?

```
from time import time
from urllib import urlopen

# vars
url = raw_input("Please enter the URL you want to test: ")

for i in range(0,100):
    start_time = time()
    pic = urlopen(url)

    if pic.getcode() == 200:
        delta_time = time() - start_time
        print "%d" % (delta_time * 100)
    else:
        print "error"
print "%d requests made. File size: %d B" % (i, len(pic.read()))
```

I'm new to Python, though, so I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Are you trying to time the whole operation (checking the file 100 times) or just one opening? Are you interested in the number of times where you could get a proper `pic.getcode()` value, or the number of times where you tried to open the url (which is gonna be 100...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some comments on your code:

1. `raw_input` is a very inflexible way to get data into a program: it is only suitable for interactive use. For more general use, you should get your data into the program in some other way, for example via command-line arguments.
2. `urllib.urlopen` [was removed in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html), so your program will be more forward-compatible if you use `urllib2.urlopen` instead. (You'll need to change the way your error handling works, because `urllib2.urlopen` deals with an error by raising an exception instead of returning a response object with a `getcode` method.)
3. The comment `# vars` does not seem to contain any information. Improve it or remove it.
4. The `range` function starts at `0` by default, so `range(0,100)` can be written more simply as `range(100)`.
5. 100 seems rather arbitrary. Why not take this as a command-line parameter too?
6. The variable `pic` seems poorly named. Is it short for *picture*? The `urlopen` function returns a *file-like object* from which the *resource* at the URL can be read. The [examples in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples) accordingly use `f` or `r`  as variable names.
7. I assume that this code is only going to be used for testing your own site. If it were going to be used to time the fetching of resources from public sites, it would be polite (a) to respect the [robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) and (b) to not fetch resources as fast as possible, but to `sleep` for a while between each request.
8. If an attempt to fetch the resource fails, you probably want to exit the loop rather than fail again many times.
9. You say in your post that the code is supposed to time "the entire transaction", but it does not do this. It only times how long it takes to call `urlopen`. This generally completes quickly, because it just reads the headers, not the entire resource. You do read the resource once (at the very end), but outside the timing code.
10. You multiply the time taken by 100 and then print it as an integer. This seems unnecessarily misleading: if you want two decimal places, then why not use `"%.2f"`?
11. Finally, there's a built-in Python library [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) for measuring the execution time of a piece of code, which compensates for things like the time taken to call `time`.

So I might write something more like this:

```
from sys import argv
from timeit import Timer
from urllib2 import urlopen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = argv[1]
    n = int(argv[2])
    length = 0

    def download():
        global length, url
        f = urlopen(url)
        length += len(f.read())
        f.close()

    t = Timer(download).timeit(number = n)
    print('{0:.2f} seconds/download ({1} downloads, average length = {2} bytes)'
          .format(t / n, n, length / n))
```

Comment: Great answer - lots of info! It's not working when I try to run it though. Could it be because I have Python 2.7 installed on my system? It's telling me that argv list index is out of range

Comment: It takes two command-line arguments (the URL and the number of repetitions). Something like `python download.py http://my-server-address/ 100`

Comment: Okay I understand.. It's because I'm running the file directly when I should be opening it via command line so I can actually pass the arguments! Right?